# Google cloud storage ACL user limit

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a number of users limit on the ACL of a google storage object?
Instead of adding a endpoint database between the user and storage, I would like to add all the users who have access directly to the acl.

Let say I have 1000 users or more in that ACL defined, will it still be ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is a hard limit of 100 ACL entries. Instead, I suggest doing one of the following:

- Give permission to a Group, and manage access to that group, or
- Manage access in some other data store, like a SQL database, and decide whether to grant access to a resource as needed. Grant access by issuing signed URLs, which can be used for a brief window of time to access the object.

Comment: Do you have more information about signed url's please. I am planning to connect all android users directly to storage.

Comment: Sure! You'll want to start here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

Comment: Ok thanks, is there also a API for creating a Group?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not.